# Tab should select when i click from other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**HOME PAGE**

```
<h1>Our Services</h1>
<ul>
<li><a href="services.html">Project Management</a></li>
<li><a href="services.html">Land Development Management</a></li>
<li><a href="services.html">Site Selection and Transaction<br /> Due Diligence</a></li>
<li><a href="rservices.html">Relocation Management</a></li>
<li><a href="services.html">Construction Claims Assessment</a></li>
<li><a href="services.html">Supplier Procurement Management</a></li>
<li><a href="services.html">Scheduling</a></li>
<li><a href="services.html">Sustainable Service Management</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to click on the anchor tag and go to service.html page. 
Want to select the corresponding tab which i selected on home page.
If i use services.html#tabs-2 as a link then it works fine and go to
 the corresponding tab but i don't want my link as services.html#tabs-2.It should be services.html.

```
                               ** Service Page **
                    **It works fine when i click on tabbing.**



<script>
  $(function () {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

  });
</script>
   <script>  
   $(function () { 
    //Get the first tab in document and will assume will always use first one
    var selectedTab = $(document).find('div[class^="ui-tabs"]').first();

    //Navigation button, select tab when button click.
    $(".Footer").on('click', ':button', function () {
        var selected = selectedTab.tabs("option", "active");
        if (this.id == "btnMoveLeftTab") {
            if (selected >= 1) {
                selectedTab.tabs("option", "active", selected - 1);
            }
        } else {
            selectedTab.tabs("option", "active", selected + 1);
        }
    });
    //Tab activated, only display next on first tab, and previous in last tab
    selectedTab.tabs({
        activate: function (event, ui) { 
            var active = selectedTab.tabs("option", "active");
            var selected = selectedTab.tabs("option", "active");

            if (active == 0) {
                $("#btnMoveLeftTab").hide();
            }else if (selectedTab.find("li:not(li[style='display:none'])").size()-1 == selected){
                $("#btnMoveRightTab").hide();
            }else{
                $("#btnMoveLeftTab").show();
                $("#btnMoveRightTab").show();
            }
        }
    });
    //First time loading hide the previous button
    $("#btnMoveLeftTab").hide();
  });</script>

   <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
            <h3 class="main_h3_li">Services Offered</h3>
            <span class="full_h">CLICK AN ITEM BELOW FOR DETAILS</span>

            ** Tabbing Start From Here **


        <div class="clear"></div>
            <li role="tab" aria-controls="tab_item-0" class="resp-tab-item resp-tab-active"><a href="#tabs-1">Project Management</a></li>
            <li role="tab" aria-controls="tab_item-1" class="resp-tab-item"><a href="#tabs-2">Land Development Management</a></li>
            <li role="tab" aria-controls="tab_item-2" class="resp-tab-item"><a href="#tabs-3">Site Selection and Transaction   Due Diligence</a></li>
            <li role="tab" aria-controls="tab_item-3" class="resp-tab-item"><a href="#tabs-4">Relocation Management</a></li>
            <li role="tab" aria-controls="tab_item-4" class="resp-tab-item resp-tab-active"><a href="#tabs-5">Construction Claim Assessmen</a></li>
            <li role="tab" aria-controls="tab_item-5" class="resp-tab-item"><a href="#tabs-6">Supplier Procurement Management</a></li>
            <li role="tab" aria-controls="tab_item-6" class="resp-tab-item"><a href="#tabs-7">Scheduling </a></li>
            <li role="tab" aria-controls="tab_item-7" class="resp-tab-item"><a href="#tabs-8">Sustainable Service Manageme</a></li>
                        </ul>
```

Comment: use URL Rewriting here is a link http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/

Comment: Is there any other way except URL Rewriting Sai Ram Sudheer?

Comment: i dont know any other way to do it.

Comment: As far i can tell out of my head it should be possible on click to prevent the navigation to the new url and set the matching url by using modern javascript apis (may not work on older browsers).